# multi-instance sitecore site is "leaking" content across domains

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I have two sites running from the same instance of Sitecore:
www.domainA.org
www.domainB.com

Google has started returning links indexed from domainA.org that is actually content from domainB.com, for example:

www.domainA.org/sitecore/content/contentrootB/Destinations.aspx

(of course, contentrootB is the content root set in  for domainB)

I've been looking all day trying to find where a /sitecore link is coming from on domainA and I haven't found ANYTHING.  I've run Xenu and gotten nothing.  Interestingly, I can HTTrack to copy down the HTML from domainA to my local machine last night and got a bunch of domainB content.  But still not clue why that is happening.  It's like there is a link that is only popping up for spiders.

Any clue/suggestion/tool I can use to track this down?

Sitecore version is 6.2 rev 100507.

Comment: Please list your relevant config lines in the sites section of the web.config

Comment: I'm curious about your link structure above as it starts from the sitecore root, not the website's node root. Can you provide the details of your `<site ...>` nodes in the `web.config`?

Comment: Well, I'm curious about that too... :)  I just sent you an email with details from my web.config.

Comment: Interesting -- I responded. I'm now curious about how your `LinkManager` is configured, or how your code generates links. E.g. `<sc:link ... />` or `LinkManager.GetItemUrl()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's a sublayout or an xslt that both sites are sharing and has a hardcoded link to the home node of one of the domains.

I've had a similar issue. In our case we had an xslt for the 404 page that both domains were sharing. The xslt had a hard coded home node for domainB. 
So when domainA hit 404 it displayed the content fine but the links inside were pointing to domainB.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Finally tracked this down... you were correct.  Turns out it was a combination of three factors.  My dynamic nav menu had a badly formed link... and then this link was copied over to a static HTML page to act as the "friendly" asp.net error page... and then finally Sitecore's way-too-liberal item resolver which allowed www.domainA.com/domainB/page.aspx to be a valid link.